# Specialist evaluation for people aged under 40 years with stage 1 hypertension

Tags: human-biology, blood-pressure

Reading the [NICE clinical guideline for Hypertension](http://www.nice.org.uk/guidance/cg127/resources/guidance-hypertension-pdf) it says...

> For people aged under 40 years with stage 1 hypertension and no evidence of target organ damage, cardiovascular disease, renal disease or diabetes, consider seeking specialist evaluation of secondary causes of hypertension and a more detailed assessment of potential target organ damage.

However it is not clear in the guidelines exactly what "specialist evaluation of secondary causes of hypertension and a more detailed assessment of potential target organ damage" would entail.

I understand that it is typical to carry out blood tests to look at kidney function, thyroid function, cholesterol and glucose levels; and that further tests such as a 12-lead ECG, echocardiography and renal ultrasound scan may be ordered if necessary to test for organ damage.

My question is what further tests would be performed by a specialist on a patient aged under 40 years with stage 1 hypertension and no evidence of target organ damage, cardiovascular disease, renal disease or diabetes? I have done several searches on Google but most of the papers I've read relate to patients who already have signs of organ damage or existing disease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alongside full guidance released by NICE they also produce treatment pathways which give further advice - here is the [treatment pathway for hypertension](http://pathways.nice.org.uk/pathways/hypertension).  You've listed most of the investigations that would be considered in your original question.

Investigations that *may* be considered as appropriate include:

- Urine dipping for proteinuria or haematuria indicative of renal damage
- Measuring of plasma urea and electrolytes and estimation of glomerular filtration rate, again as an indicator of renal damage
- Measuring of plasma glucose, total cholesterol and LDL/HDL cholesterol to rule out additional risk factors as part of cardiovascular risk assessment - e.g. diabetes, hypercholestrolaemia
- Fundoscopy to examine the retina for damage resulting from hypertension
- 12 lead ECG to show any changes compatible with left ventricular hypertrophy
- Scanning for the presence of a [phaeochromocytoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pheochromocytoma) if clinically suspected

You may also find the [professional reference page on hypertension](http://www.patient.co.uk/doctor/hypertensive-emergencies) from patient.co.uk useful.